# How do I parse out n-bit elements from a byte addressable array

Tags: c, parsing, bit-fields

I have a data stream that is addressable only in 8-bit bytes, I want to parse it out into 6-bit elements and store that into an array.  Is there any best known methods to do this?

```
11110000 10101010 11001100
```

into

an array like

```
111100|001010|101011|001100
```

(can have zero padding, just needs to be addressable this way)

and the data is an  8-bit array that is also a multiple of 6-bits , not really endless

Comment: Is this a constant, endless stream of 5-bit data elements, or a known structure that repeats?

Comment: Maybe there is some error correction redundancy, always assuming the best ;-)

Comment: Are those bytes written with the least significant bit first or the most significant? In other words, is that (15, 85, 51) or (240, 170, 204) ?

Comment: It's bad form to change your question from "5" bits to "6" bits after people have started to answer your question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Depends how much bits a byte has on your particular architecture. On a six bit architecture it is quite simple :-)

Assuming a 8 bits per byte architecture you will have to do something along the lines:

```
int sixbits(unsigned char* datastream, unsigned int n) {
    int bitpos = n*6;
    return (datastream[bitpos/8] >> bitpos%8)    // lower part of the five bit group
        + (datastream[bitpos/8+1] << 8-bitpos%8) // if bitpos%8>2, we need to add some carry bits from the next char
        & 0x3f;                                  // and finally mask the lowest 6 bits
}
```

Where n is the n-th 6 bit group. Any decent compiler will substitute the division with shifts and the moduli with ands. Just use this function in a loop to fill up your destination array.

Comment: +1 Nice solution, much faster than mine. You might want to fix the 'error: `index' undeclared' though.

Comment: Thanks, fixed. Removed some unecessary parenthesis, to make some more place for the comments ;-) For non-C people the precedence should be clear with the additional whitespaces.

Answer (score 1):

You count your 5 bit sequences, read each byte, shift the bits based on your counter and the expected word position (by xor-ing pieces from neighboring byte words), and form new correctly aligned byte words that you then process.

I hope you don't expect code ...

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using bit fiddling:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    unsigned char source[3] = { 15, 85, 51 };
    unsigned char destination[4];
    memset(destination, 0, 4);
    for (int i = 0; i < (8 * 3); ++i)
    {
        destination[i / 6] |= ((source[i / 8] >> (i % 8) & 1) << (i % 6));
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < 4; ++j)
        printf("%d ", destination[j]);
}
```

Output:

```
15 20 53 12
```

Note that this starts working from the five *least* significant bits.

```
      15       85       51
11110000 10101010 11001100
111100 001010 101011 001100
    15     20     53     12
```

To get most significant first, do this instead:

```
destination[i / 6] |= ((source[i / 8] >> (7 - (i % 8))) & 1) << (5 - (i % 6));
```

This works as in your example, assuming you wrote the most significant bit first:

```
240      170      204
11110000 10101010 11001100
111100 001010 101011 001100
60     10     43     12
```

Comment: Why is `source[6]` when you only use 3 indices? Also, I would set `unsigned char destinatio[4] = {0};` just for safety, but I don't know that it matters.

Comment: 1) It was six in an earlier version. I just forgot to change it. 2) I memset the destination array to zero on the next line.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a struct like this:

```
struct bit5
{
    unsigned int v1 : 5;
    unsigned int v2 : 5;
    unsigned int v3 : 5;
    unsigned int v4 : 5;
    unsigned int v5 : 5;
    unsigned int v6 : 5;
    unsigned int v7 : 5;
    unsigned int v8 : 5;
};
```

And then cast your array of bytes to the `struct bit5` every 8 bytes (40 bits = 8 groups of 5 bits, fits in 8 bytes) to get the 5 bit chunks. Say:

```
unsigned char* array; // a byte array that you want to convert
int i;
struct bit5* pBit5;

for(i = 0; i < (int)(SIZE_OF_ARRAY / 8); i++)
    pBit5 = (struct bit5*)((int)array + i * 8);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would consider using a BitStream.  It will allow you to read one bit at a time.  You can shift that bit directly into place (using << n).  It may not perform as well as reading an 8-bit byte at a time but it would certainly be cleaner looking code.

Answer (score 0):

How about this Union?

```
union _EIGHT_TO_SIX_ {

    struct {

       unsigned char by6Bit0 : 6;
       unsigned char by6Bit1 : 6;
       unsigned char by6Bit2 : 6;
       unsigned char by6Bit3 : 6;

    } x6;

    struct {

       unsigned char by8Bit0;
       unsigned char by8Bit0;
       unsigned char by8Bit0;

    } x8;
}
```

Setting by8Bitx will automatically fill in by6Bitx ~~~

Comment: also add __attribute__((packed)) for GNU compilers